# prove that positive definite matrix is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is to prove that positive definite matrix is invertible. I've proved that positive definite matrix has null space of zero vector. So actually we can prove that a matrix has an null space of zero vector is invertible. How to prove this? I need a basic way of proof without using other conclusions (like all eigenvalues are positive so it's invertible or a positive definite matrix is nonsingular so its inverse exists) used in the proving process.  Thank you!

Comment: The null space can never be empty because $0$ is always there.

Answer (score 3):

Now that you know that $A\in M_n$ it is injective, use the [rank-nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) to deduce that
$$
\mbox{rank}A=n-\mbox{null}A=n.
$$
It follows that $A$ is also surjective, hence invertible.